# SQL find median of col2 for every distinct value of col1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, median

I'm trying to calculate median of time for every distinct value in column1, which stores some kind of id's. The second column stores time in miliseconds. I want to calculate median of records for every id. I have this:

```
Declare @Median varchar(max)
SELECT @Median = PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5)
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ExecTime) OVER () 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ExecTime
    FROM logs
    WHERE Message Like '<%'
) AS median 
SELECT @Median as Median --, Name
```

Which calculates median of all values in the col2 (I deleted extra conditions which are not relevant at this point). I think it's just one step away from the solution but I can't catch it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `partition by` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ExecTime) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) as median 
FROM logs l
WHERE l.Message Like '<%';
```